# How to invoke a component on handleSubmit in react

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am learning react. I have created a form and on submit I want to render another(Info here) component and I am unable to do so.here is my code example.

App.js

```
class App extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props)
this.state = { username: '' }
this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
}

handleChange(event) {
this.setState({ value: event.target.value })
}

handleSubmit(event) {
alert(this.state.username)
event.preventDefault()
}

render() {
return (
  <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
    <input
      type="text"
      value={this.state.username}
      onChange={this.handleChange}
    />
     <button type="button" class ="button" value="Info" onClick={this.handleSubmit} component = {Summary}>Summary</button>
  </form>
)
}
}
```

Info.js

```
class Info extends React.Component{
{more logic and code for this component}
render(){
return (<h1>Welcome To Info</h1>)
}


}
export default Info
```

Comment: check this your improved code https://stackoverflow.com/a/58580004/6544460

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way

```
class App extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = { username: '', showInfo: false }
  this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
  this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
}

handleChange(event) {
 this.setState({ value: event.target.value })
}

handleSubmit(event) {
 alert(this.state.username)
 event.preventDefault()
 this.setState({showInfo: true});
}

render() {
  return (
    <div>
     <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
       <input
         type="text"
         value={this.state.username}
         onChange={this.handleChange}
       />
       <button type="button" class ="button" value="Info" onClick={this.handleSubmit} component = {Summary}>Summary</button>
     </form>
     {this.state.showInfo ? <Info /> : null}
   </div>
  )
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function Info(props){
  return <h3>{props.username}</h3>
}
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = { username: '' }
  this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
  this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
  }

  handleChange =(event)=> {
  this.setState({ username: event.target.value })
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
  alert(this.state.username)
  event.preventDefault()
  }

  render() {
  return (
   <div> 
    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={this.state.username}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
      />
       <button type="button" class ="button" value="Info" 
       onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Summary</button>
    </form>
    <Info {...this.state}/>
    </div>
  )
 }
}
```